# 2-Legged OAuth for Google Drive from Android?

Tags: android, google-drive-api

Can I use Google Drive to upload images through an Android application. I also would not want the user to be involved in the process of authentication because all the images should be uploaded to a specific user's Drive only. I think this is only possible through a 2-legged OAuth but does a 2-legged OAuth exist for the Drive??

Thank YOu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2-legged OAuth does not exist on Google Drive. The nearest behaviour achievable is by using Service Accounts with impersonation. If you have a google apps domain, you can use Provisioning API to find the users of the domain and impersonate them progammatically